# Copy array on array value change into another component and change component view

Tags: html, typescript, service, angular5

I have a filter function that changes the values of an array in the app component. What I want is whenever this function changes the values of the array, the array will be copied into my other custom component and then instantly change the `component.html`(view) file. But now the problem is that changes only occur in the html/view file after the filter function has been called again. There is a click delay. It gives values of the previous function call. Say, if I check one checkbox, the array is changed but the custom view file is only updated either if I uncheck the checkbox or make a different choice. Below is my code structure. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Service File**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class FilteredService {

  public recordChanges: Observable<any>;
  public recordObserver: Observer<any>;
  public invokeEvent: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor() { }
}
```

**App component file**

```js
import { FilteredService } from './services/filtered.service';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public records$: Array<model.IProduct> = [];

  constructor(
  ...
     private filteredService: FilteredService,
  ...
  )

  ngOnInit() {

  '''
  this.otherService.filterParamChanges.subscribe(params => {
        this.onchangeRecords(params);
      });
  ...
  }


  onchangeRecords(params){
  ...
  ...
  changeRecordArray(params);
  this.filteredService.invokeEvent.next(this.records$);
  this.router.navigate(['/custom.html']);
 }
 ...
}
```

**custom ts file**

```js
...
import { FilteredService } from '../../services/filtered.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom',
  templateUrl: './custom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom.component.scss']
})

export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

  public records$: Array<model.IProduct> = [];
  ...
  constructor(
  ...
    private filteredService: FilteredService,
   ...
  ) {  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredService.invokeEvent.subscribe((value) => {
      this.getFiltered(value);
    });
  }

  getFiltered(newRecords) {
    this.records$ = newRecords;
  }
}
```

**custom html**

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-product [ngForOf]="records$">
  ... display array values here ..
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you create an stackblitz to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @SergiDoteTeixidor, I don't know how to create a stackblitz yet but I will let you know soon as I have something close to what I mean.

Comment: or can share the project in order to check your implementation?

Comment: stackblitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @SergiDoteTeixidor this pretty much has the structure of the main code. But I find it hard to debug in stackblitz. And apparently I cant continue from where I left off so everything disappears. I hope you find it and its understandable. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-symjzu

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hb6efa should be same.

Comment: your stackblitz is not working at all!!

Comment: Now is working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hb6efa

Comment: what is yout problem at this point?

Comment: this is exactly how it is supposed to be working. What exactly did you change? can you put it as an answer so that i can accept it? Also one more question, the button clicked(filter) is shared in other components in the same way. I hope that doesnt matter. Thanks by the way :).

Comment: I fixed the routes too. its ok now. same stackblitz u shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change only styles and few thing more, nothing about typescript code.

Yes, and the routes, i didn't remember. That's all

Comment: alright. am going to look at my original project code once again . if something happens, I will let you know.